# Convert LINQ C# to VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

Can any one convert this c# linq code to VB?i tried developerfusion,didnt worked

```
   DataTable dt = dt1.Copy();
        var result = dt
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(r => r.Field<string>(0))
            .Select(s => string.Join("",
                                 s.Select((x, i) => x == '0'
                                                    ? " "
                                                    : (i + 1).ToString()))
             ).ToList();
```

what i  tried is

```
    Dim dt As DataTable = dt1.Copy()
    Dim result = dt.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(r) r.Field(Of String)(0)).[Select](Function(s) String.Join("", s.[Select](Function(x, i) If(x = "0"c, " ", (i + 1).ToString())))).ToList()
```

But It shows error

```
 Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in extension method 'Public Function Select(Of S)(selector As System.Func(Of String, S)) As System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(Of S)' defined in 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.
```

my datatable which is having only single column and is look like 
for 1st row  1000000
for second row 0010000
fro third row 0100000 etc. and what i want to get is replacing all 0s with blank space and all 1s with its position number ie; for first row the desired out put is like (1000000).for second row (0030000) and for third (0200000). like that

Comment: What you mean by `didn't work` ??

Comment: y these much down votes?

Comment: Can you explains the error please? It seems fine to me though !

Comment: i updated my question with the error which i am getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working sample: http://dotnetfiddle.net/LNksSW

**The reason for the error you're getting is that you're missing `Imports System.Linq` at the top of your file.**

```
Dim dt as DataTable = new DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("col1")
dt.Rows.Add("1000000")
dt.Rows.Add("0010000")
dt.Rows.Add("0100000")      

Dim result = dt _
    .AsEnumerable() _
    .Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)(0)) _
    .Select(Function(s) string.Join("", s.Select(Function(x, i) _
        If(x = "0", "0", (i + 1).ToString())))).ToList()

For Each i As String in result
    Console.WriteLine(i)
Next
```

Comment: getting error 'Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in extension method 'Public Function Select(Of S)(selector As System.Func(Of String, S)) As System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(Of S)' defined in 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.'

Comment: @Cronaldo - Are you able to post a small sample of what your datatable looks like? Or better still create a sample at http://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: @Cronaldo - here's a working dotnetfiddle sample - http://dotnetfiddle.net/VTq4j3

Answer (score 0):

The exception is explicitly telling you to specify the data type(s) in the Select

```vb
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
Dim result = dt.
    AsEnumerable().
    Select(Function(r As DataRow) r.Field(Of String)(0)).
    Select(Function(s As String) String.Join(
               "", s.Select(Function(x As Char, i As Integer)
                                Return If(x = "0"c, " ", (i + 1).ToString())
                            End Function))).
    ToList()
```